# What could be the issue for PHPs rename() to throw an error/warning Access Denied (code 5)

Tags: php

Ok, so Im trying to use rename(path to directory) and it seems pretty trivial even though I have read about alot of issues related to it. Whenever I try to rename a specific directory it works fine, but with another directory within the same directory, same file permissions etc, it produces a warning and rename() function is not successful. What are more reasons other than file permissions that produce such a warning ? I'm puzzled!

Comment: File permissions of the parent, file permissions of the target parent, etc. It could even be a difference in mounted disks. What does your _error/warning_ say?

Comment: File owner:group perhaps ?

Comment: @wrikken both directories Im testing are in the same directory and thier permissions are in fact identical! and the path Im providing is also correct.

Comment: On the same disk? Is `safe_mode` active? What OS? SELinux install perhaps? If you're overwriting a directory (which you seem to do as you claim you have 2 directories there), is each and every descendant deletable by you?

Comment: Ok I think I know what the problem is, but i'm not sure I know how to solve it! So Im scanning a directory using scandir($path) 
and whatever is in that path, im listing files and folders through php generating xhtml.. hence the subdirectories Im trying to rename resides in the 'path' I used for scandir(path). Im guessing its still open and therefore unmodifieable! How shall I go about it? any  ideas? Im not using handles since im using scandir!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! The issue was what I suspected! The only logical explanation for an Access denied warning was that the handle was still open! This was the case as I was using scandir(), I switched to the good old php4's equivalent solution.. opendir(); readdir(); AND closedir(); 
Those 3 steps are crucial when working with directories! If anyone knows of an equivalent to closdir() when using scandir(), please post a solution! Thanks and Regards